# Should collective names include "collective"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

Right now the collective for the R language is called the [R Language Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language). That's fine, but the result is that collective-associated questions are tagged, redundantly, as "Part of R Language Collective Collective" (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76142846/contrasts-errors-in-logistic-regression-in-r)).

[image: screenshot showing "Part of R Language Collective Collective"]

Is this a naming-convention problem or a UI/display-design problem?

Comment: The “Collective Collective” part is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This repetition issue has been fixed.